# I have three lists and I want to create a csv file

Tags: python, list

I have three lists namely names, artists, and albums. I want to create a csv such that the first elements of each is in one row, and then next element in other and so on.

For eg.

```
names = ['Tell Me It's Okay', 'Cry', Oblivion']
albums = ['Tell Me It's Okay', 'Cry', 'Oblivion']
artists = ['Fell', 'Gryffin', 'Alex']
```

I want the output in csv as

Tell Me It's Okay,Tell Me It's Okay, Fell

Cry,Cry,Gryffin

Oblivion,Oblivion,Alex

Comment: Please show your efforts/research and ask a specific question about any problems you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip these lists together to make it work. Something like this:

```py
names = ['Tell Me It\'s Okay', 'Cry', 'Oblivion']
albums = ['Tell Me It\'s Okay', 'Cry', 'Oblivion']
artists = ['Fell', 'Gryffin', 'Alex']

data = [','.join(record) for record in zip(names, albums, artists)]
with open('output.csv','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list have invalid strings. If you have single quote(') inside the string, then you need to wrap your strings with double quote(").

You can try:

```
with open("xxx.csv", 'w') as fp:
fp.write("header1,header2")
for lst in [list1, list2, list3]:
    fp.write(','.join(fp))
```

the 2nd line inputs the header of each row that you can edit as you want.
list1, list2 & list3 are the lists that you have.
xxx should replaced with the name you want of your csv file

Comment: I get only Name,Album,Artists in my csv file. I have named my header as those. I don't get any list element.